# frequency of all elements of list in Python

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list  `l = [1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,6]`
I don't want to use  `l.count(element)`  method. I don't want to use for loop or iterator.
output like  `{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use collection's `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```